# mysql : Is it possible to ignore some tables in cold backup?

Tags: mysql, backup

We take every day the backup of a folder from production to uat with rsync.

That folder, among others, contains the physical files of a mysql database.

Is it possible to exclude some tables during the backup process explicitly with rsync (not mysqldump)?

If yes, which table files should I exclude in the mysql directory?

Thank you!

Comment: i am not sure what you mean, which tables you want to exclude

Comment: You may, but this is not recommended strongly. All existing tables are registered in system tables, and the absense of a table may cause unpredictable result - till server non-starting while using the partial backup as server datadir. Maybe such issue may be solved while providing old table body file instead of skipped actual one, maybe not. Anycase, "Criterion of truth is practice" - test recovering possibility while using such partial backup..